# typescript: the method Status will be undefined during extends MemoryStream

Tags: typescript, extends

If I remove the `extends MemoryStream` below, then everything works as expected - the status method can be called.
But if I use `extends MemoryStream`, then the status method becomes `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

```ts
import MemoryStream from 'memorystream';

export interface ResponseInterface extends NodeJS.WritableStream{
    status(s: number): ResponseInterface
}

export class FakeResponce extends MemoryStream implements ResponseInterface {
    status(s: number): ResponseInterface{
        console.log("status work!") 
        return this;
    }
}

const a : ResponseInterface = new FakeResponce();
console.log(`status is ${a.status}`);  // status is undefined
a.status(); // ERROR
```

Updated:

I fixed it. **But is this really the best way?**

```
import MemoryStream from 'memorystream';

export interface ResponseInterface extends NodeJS.WritableStream{
    status(s: number): ResponseInterface
}

export class FakeResponce extends MemoryStream implements ResponseInterface {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.status = (s: number): ResponseInterface => {
            console.log("status work!") 
            return this;
        }
    }
    status: (s: number) => ResponseInterface
}

const a : ResponseInterface = new FakeResponce();
console.log(`status is ${a.status}`);
a.status(); // Ok
```

Comment: Where does the MemoryStream class come from? Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`memorystream`](https://github.com/JSBizon/node-memorystream/blob/c4285c96c40e35173fd5db37bc586970e235dbbe/index.js#L31) uses [util.inherits](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinheritsconstructor-superconstructor) from nodejs, which is not compatible with ES6 `extends`, see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4179

A workaround would be changing it to a property instead of a method, which is what your fix does. But the implementation can be inline with the declaration instead of separating to within the constructor.

```
export class FakeResponce extends MemoryStream implements ResponseInterface {

    status : (s: number) => ResponseInterface = (s) => {
        console.log("status work!")
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `memorystream` is [npm's one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memorystream).

Yes, you will not inherit members correctly without calling base class' constructor by `super()`.